# Constant for Sobolev inequality on annulus

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, sobolev-spaces

does anyone know a reference where I can find the best constant for Sobolev inequality on an annulus?

More precisely, I know by Rellich-Kondrachov Theorem (Brezis, Theorem 9.16) that, given $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded and of class $C^1$, we have the embedding
\begin{equation}
W^{1,2}(\Omega)\subset L^q(\Omega),\quad\forall q\in[p,+\infty).
\end{equation}
This is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_{L^q(\Omega)}\le C(q,\Omega) \|u\|_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}.
\end{equation}
I was wondering what is known about $C(q,\Omega)$ in case $\Omega$ is the annulus
\begin{equation}
A_x(\delta,\tau):=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^2,\,|\,\delta\le|x-y|\le\tau\}.
\end{equation}
Thank you very much!

Comment: you might just retsart the proof given in Brezis by keeping track of your constant

Comment: Yes, it is certainly a possibility. However, I fear I would hardly get the sharp constant

Comment: Don't be lazy dude you have to brainstorm a bite

Comment: I mean, of course I can go through the proof, it's not about lazyness. My question was just if anyone knew a reference, that's it. If nobody knows it, I will braimstorm, no doubt. People write papers about optimal constants, so I figured that maybe it would be out of reach by me.